# Connect the wires without setting off the bomb

Tags: no-computers, graph-theory, construction

You just saw a planted time bomb! Just 5 minutes are remaining until it explodes and as you are in currently in a rural area (no bomb disposal squad) and you know how bombs usually work it is up to you to decide it.
The interesting part of the circuit is below:

[image]

To defuse the bomb you have to connect each same-colored pair of nodes (circles) except the red ones. Short circuiting subject to the rules mentioned below or **connecting two different colored nodes** will set off the bomb.
The 4 master nodes (red) have to be connected such that **you can start from any master node and go across wires and come back to the same node, without visiting any node except itself or any wire twice**.
Unfortunately you didn't come prepared for this situation, so the only things you have  that could be useful are some old wire and a scissor. As those wires are prone to short circuiting, **no two wires can touch, and no wire can touch the circuit boundary**. Also you are supposed to treat the circuit like it is 2D, as the wires are flimsy and couldn't hold a height. You cannot use the scissor for anything except cutting wires. **Wires do not have to be straight and you cannot connect a wire to the middle of an another wire, all wires must start and end at nodes**.
Can you save the day?

**Abstraction:**
In the diagram, connect the nodes with edges so that no two different color nodes are connected, same color node pairs are connected, the red nodes form a cycle, no edge touches the boundary and no two edges intersect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This solution works:

> [image]

(Places where the wires are close together can be pushed apart a bit - there aren't any crossed wires, though.)

My strategy:

> The only sorts of topological restrictions involve lines where both ends must be connected to the edge of the grid. That's the only way to cut off any paths - in all other cases, you can just move wires around other wires as necessary. So there's an easy way to solve this puzzle: just do the red loop last, because it's the only thing that can cut off any future lines.
>
>   Nothing else cuts the grid into different regions, so as long as you do the red last it's impossible to *not* solve the puzzle!

Comment: Wow, congratulations on solving it this quickly! :D